# Wordpress Plugin That Can Create Username and Password by Uploading CSV file

Tags: wordpress

Is there a WordPress plugin that can create username and passwords based on CSV file upload or by copy and pasting?

Comment: Asking for product recommendation is off-topic. Just go and google it or search on WordPress plugins page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [this plugin](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv-with-meta/) to create users with upload (but maybe you need to convert your CSV to XLS) or [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-multiple-users/) to create users and copy-paste their logins-passwords.

But anyway, you can find some other solutions in [Google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUA739UA739&ei=e3t9WteGH8S4sQHp-b_QCw&q=wordpress%20plugin%20to%20create%20import%20users%20csv&oq=wordpress%20plugin%20to%20create%20import%20users%20csv&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6846.6846.0.6931.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.34DtKb39BA0).

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv-with-meta/

> Clean and easy-to-use Import users plugin. It includes custom user
>   meta to be included automatically from a CSV file and delimitation
>   auto-detector. It also is able to send a mail to each user imported
>   and all the meta data imported is ready to edit into user profile.